# Get the name of local branches tracking a given remote branch

Tags: git

I am trying to find which local branch would have been the default when cloning a git repository.

In this particular context I am able to assume the remote is called `origin`. I can get the default branch for `origin` using `git symbolic-ref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`. This returns something like `refs/remotes/origin/develop`.

I now need to find which local branches are set up to track `origin/develop`. Obviously it's almost certainly going to be `develop`, so I could just do some string manipulation to replace `remotes/origin/` and end up with `refs/heads/develop`. However, I would like to avoid making that assumption.

I'm currently grepping it out of the result of `git branch -vv` (specifically `git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name $(git branch -vv | grep "\[$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref $(git symbolic-ref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD))\]" | awk '{print $1}')`). However, this is very brittle, especially as the branch name can appear in the commit message.

I am currently using git 2.18, though could upgrade if newer verisons have a feature required to make this better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also take advantage of the `%(if) %(then) [%(else)] %(end)` construct inside `for-each-ref` [formats](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#_field_names).

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(if:origin/<remoteBranch>)%(upstream:short)%(then)%(refname:short)%(end)" refs/heads
```

*(As a sidenote, in case you have many branches, avoid the blank lines noise by adding* `| sort -u` *)*

---

Finally, this is a lot more convenient in an alias :

```
git config --global alias.get-branches-pointing-to '!f() { git for-each-ref --format="%(if:equals=origin/$1)%(upstream:short)%(then)%(refname:short)%(end)" refs/heads | sort -u; }; f'

git get-branches-pointing-to <yourRemoteBranch>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
git for-each-ref refs/heads --format='%(refname:short) %(upstream:short)' |
while read branch upstream; do 
    if [ "$upstream" == origin/master ]; then
        echo branch "$branch" tracks "$upstream"
    fi
done
```

See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref